# Angular4 async pipe is losing observer reference with mdDialog

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-material, mddialog, angular-pipe

Let's say I have a component named `FooComponent` and in the html template there is an element using an async pipe `[data]="messageService.messages | async"`.

In `MessageService`, the property `messages` is a BehaviorSubject:

```
private _messages = new BehaviorSubject(this._loadedMessages[this.environmentId]);
get messages(): BehaviorSubject<Message[]> { return this._messages; }
```

In `FooComponent` I can open a `mdDialog` and in this dialog a function of `MessageService` is called which is changing the value of the subject behavior:

```
this._messages.next(this._loadedMessages[this.environmentId]);
```

The problem is, after closing the dialog, in the function `Subject.prototype.next(value)` of `SubjectBehavior`,`FooComponent` is not an observer anymore.

I know that aync pipe prevent memory leaks by unsubscribing on component destruction, but opening a dialog does'nt destroy `FooComponent`...

Why I am losing the observer reference?